# regex matches numbers, but not letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that looks like this:

> [if-abc] 12345 [if-def] 67890 [/if][/if]

I have the following regex:

```
/\[if-([a-z0-9-]*)\]([^\[if]*?)\[\/if\]/s
```

This matches the inner brackets just like I want it to. However, when I replace the 67890 with text (ie. abcdef), it doesn't match it.

> [if-abc] 12345 [if-def] abcdef [/if][/if]

I want to be able to match ANY characters, including line breaks, except for another opening bracket `[if-`.

Comment: Write a text without 'i' or 'f' in it, it will work. Your regex has a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part doesn't work like you think it does:

```
[^\[if]
```

This will match a single character that is neither of `[`, `i` or `f`. Regardless of the combination. You can mimic the desired behavior using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) though:

```
~\[if-([a-z0-9-]*)\]((?:(?!\[/?if).)*)\[/if\]~s
```

I've also included closing tags in the lookahead, as this avoid the ungreedy repetition (which is usually worse performance-wise). Plus, I've changed the delimiters, so that you don't have to escape the slash in the pattern.

So this is the interesting part `((?:(?!\[/?if).)*)` explained:

```
(         # capture the contents of the tag-pair
  (?:     # start a non-capturing group (the ?: are just a performance
          # optimization). this group represents a single "allowed" character
    (?!   # negative lookahead - makes sure that the next character does not mark
          # the start of either [if or [/if (the negative lookahead will cause
          # the entire pattern to fail if its contents match)
      \[/?if
          # match [if or [/if
    )     # end of lookahead
    .     # consume/match any single character
  )*      # end of group - repeat 0 or more times
)         # end of capturing group
```

Comment: Your function works, thanks.. and also thanks for the explanation, i'll have to go through it a few more times to get it

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a little results in:

```
/\[if-([a-z0-9-]+)\](.+?)(?=\[if)/s
```

Running it on `[if-abc] 12345 [if-def] abcdef [/if][/if]`

Results in a first match as: `[if-abc] 12345`

Your groups are: `abc` and `12345`

And modifying even further:

```
/\[if-([a-z0-9-]+)\](.+?)(?=(?:\[\/?if))/s
```

matches both groups. Although the delimiter `[/if]` is not captured by either of these.

**NOTE:** Instead of matching the delimeters I used a lookahead (`(?=)`) in the regex to stop when the text ahead matches the lookahead.

Comment: I think the goal is to match only the inner pair, instead of the outer or both.

Comment: @m.buettner Why match only one with a Regex when you can match multiple? He's got more than one in the string so ti would need to be matched at some point.

Comment: It's a nested structure... so matching `[if-abc] 12345` seems like an incomplete/useless match to me. Since counting nesting levels is hard to impossible in regex, it would make sense to match only the innermost pair (maybe to replace it with something else to be able to repeat the process and work from the inside out). Plus, it's simply what the OP specified in the question.

Comment: that's the idea, i only need to get the innermost one and then loop the modified string again through the same function

Comment: @user2103849 Thanks for the clarification - I see that as a requirement. All I have to add to that then is that parsing nested structures with a regular expression is going to be difficult, I don't see anyone who's addressed how to pull the inner group out only.

Comment: @izuriel that's exactly what my pattern does?

Comment: @m.buettner Yea sorry. I seem to have missed you matching the closing `[/if]` - my fault.

Answer (score -1):

Use a period to match any character.

Comment: Use a period where, why use a period - what does it do? How will that make a difference?

Comment: Carefully, read my comment.  "Use a period to match any character".  So, per your question "I want to match any character", you would use a period "." To match any character.  Although based on your comment, I'd highly recommend that you go back and read the corresponding regex manual.

Comment: I was posting a comment to back up the downvote that I applied to the answer. "Use a period to match any character" is hardly a solution to the problem presented while it address a small portion of text given from the post.